# Write a continuous quine (quine-variant)

Tags: code-golf, quine

> Let's define a 2-quine as a program that prints its source code two times. For example, if the program `ABC` printed `ABCABC`, it would be a 2-quine.
>
> Let's define a 3-quine as a program that prints its source code three times. For example, if the program `ABC` printed `ABCABCABC`, it would be a 3-quine.
>
> Let's define a *n*-quine as a program that prints its source code *n* times.

Your task is to write a 2-quine, that prints a 3-quine, that prints a 4-quine, that prints a 5-quine, etc...

For example, here is an example of a valid submission (which is fictional of course):

```
AB
```

which prints

```
ABAB
```

which prints

```
ABABABABABAB
```

which prints

```
ABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABAB
```

etc.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73222/12012) [Also related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69504/12012)

Comment: You should explicitly forbid programming languages where a 0-byte program is a quine. Otherwise I would say: "**QBasic - 0 bytes!**"

Comment: @MartinRosenau [Those are forbidden by default.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5337/8478)

Comment: I challenge someone to do this in a purely functional language, because I can't figure it out...

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21831/program-that-creates-larger-versions-of-itself-quine-variant)

Comment: @CamilStaps Just did it in Underload, but that's a bit of a cheat.

Comment: @CamilStaps I figured out how to do it in `C` but I can't because online IDEs for C lock the program's file's attributes up and I can't read them. Anyways, what you do is make sure your program is just 1 line of code and ends with `//` this way when it repeats itself the repeats are all commented out, that way you don't get errors for defining your `main(){}` function more than once. Your quine also contains a for loop for printing itself out and the number of times that loops is based on your file size which can be read from the pre-processor `__FILE__`. So the bigger the file, the more loops

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw that's great, but C is not a [purely functional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_programming).

Comment: @CamilStaps My apologies, misunderstood the definition of purely functional; thanks for the link!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw no problem. And of course, you can add your implementation to the answers here. That it does not work in an online IDE is not a problem as far as I know, especially since most people have a C compiler on their installation already :)

Answer (score 3):

### QBasic (224 bytes incl. trailing CR+LF)

(Tested with QBasic/MS-DOS on a virtual machine as well as with FreeBASIC with "-lang qb" setting)

```
a$="a$=:l=l+1:if l>y then f=f+1:y=y*f+y+f:while x<=y:x=x+1:print mid$(a$,1,3)+chr$(34)+a$+chr$(34)+mid$(a$,4):wend":l=l+1:if l>y then f=f+1:y=y*f+y+f:while x<=y:x=x+1:print mid$(a$,1,3)+chr$(34)+a$+chr$(34)+mid$(a$,4):wend
```

Comment: Nice to see QBasic as the first answer to a question! Check out my [QBasic quine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47119/16766) for some ideas that might be able to shorten this a good bit. Also, I don't think you need to count the trailing CR+LF.

Comment: @DLosc The 2-quine generated must contain CR+LF between the lines. For this reason the CR+LF is definitely a part of the program and I have to count it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Why CR+LF and not LF?

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6 (REPL), 52 bytes

```
var a=a||'';$=_=>a+=`$=${$};$();`.repeat(a?1:2);$();
```

Initial working implementation, may be golfable.

```js
y.onclick=_=>z.innerText=eval("var a=a||'';$=_=>a+=`$=${$};$();`.repeat(a?1:2);$();".repeat(x.value))
```

```html
<input id=x><button id=y>Submit!</button><pre id=z></pre>
```

## Explanation

Based on my usual quine implementation (`` $=_=>`$=${$};$()`;$() ``).

`var a||''` coerces `a` to an empty string if it isn't defined; otherwise, `a` is left as is. `a` will store our final result.

Each function call, `a` will be checked to see if it is empty/falsy. The first function call will append 2 copies of the quine because `a` is empty; subsequent calls will only append 1 copy because `a` is no longer empty.

The last function call will output the final value of `a` after finishing.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 154 bytes

```
s=DATA.read.lines;s+=s[0,2];n=s.size/4;k=1;n/=k+=1while n>0;puts s*k
__END__
s=DATA.read.lines;s+=s[0,2];n=s.size/4;k=1;n/=k+=1while n>0;puts s*k
__END__
```

The trailing newline matters.

This program first duplicates itself; the output triplicates itself; that output quadruplicates itself, etc.

Thus the **n**-th program is a repetition of these 4 lines, **n!** times.

`s=DATA.read.lines;s+=s[0,2];` gets us the current source code as an array of lines. We take its length, divide it by 4, compute the inverse factorial, add one, then print `s` that many times.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 117 bytes

```python
for x in 1,0:
 exec(s:="if x%2:a=1;d={}\nx or~input('for x in 1,0:\\n exec(s:=%r)#'%s*~-a*d[a-1]);a+=1;d[x]=a;x*=a")#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SKFCITNPwVDHwIpLIbUiNVmj2MpWKTNNoULVyCrR1tA6xba6NiavQiG/qC4zr6C0REMdRVNMTB5cm2qRprK6arFWnW6iVkp0oq5hrKZ1ojbIjOiKWNtE6wot20QlTeX//wE)

### How it works :

- `for x in 1,0:` allows me to iterate through the code twice
- then I execute some code
- `#` at the end comment the `for x in 1,0:` if the "base" is repeated multiple times

the code executed :

```python
if x%2: # execute if x=1 (happen only once at the start, 
        # after that x will always be a multiple of 2)
    a=1  
    d={}

# if x==0: print the quine the right number of time then crash
x or~input('for x in 1,0:\\n exec(s:=%r)#'%s*~-a*d[a-1])

a+=1   # a increments itelf by one for each line of the code
d[x]=a # store (a-1)! and a
x*=a   # x = a!
```

If the actual code is a `n` quine, it has `(n-1)!` times the "base" and should print it `n!` times:

- Because `a` is incremented by 1 each line, after the first iteration of the `for` loop, a is equal to `(n-1)!+1`.
- I then search `a-1` into `d` (wich store relation beetween `(k-1)!` and `k`) to find `n`.
- I multiply `n` by `a-1` to get `n!`
- I print this number times the "base"